# split a column value based on a delimiter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose I have an entries under a column 'URL' like so:

---

URL

---

"GET /books/fiction?id=324223"
"GET /classroom/ HTTP/1.0"
"GET /register.php HTTP/1.0" 
"POST /thankyou.php HTTP/1.0" 
"GET /register.php?error=alreadyregistered HTTP/1.0" 
"POST /processlogin.php?next=%2Fregister.php%3Ferror%3Dalreadyregistered HTTP/1.0" 
"GET /register.php?error=alreadyregistered HTTP/1.0" 
"GET /books/fiction?id=324273"

I need a query that will help me get just the words enclosed in the first pair of slashes ,'/' from the URL. Eg. 'classroom','register' etc...

And the entries arent limited to these.. So i'd need a generic query rather than a specific one..Help?

Comment: Why can't you  do this in post-processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick (if I understand the question correctly):

```
$request = "GET /books/fiction?id=324223";

// captures URI from request string
$request_array = explode( ' ', $request );
$request_uri = $request_array[ 1 ];

// captures anything between / and . or /
preg_match( '#\/(.*?)[./]#', $request_uri, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: This is what I saw first and it worked like a charm :) :) After a lil bit of editing...

As in..

isset(matches[1])
var_dump($matches[1]); //for my requirement..

Thanks Ondrej :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select substring_index(substring_index('http://books/serious?id=32423','//',-1),'/',1)
```

Comment: Thanks for that Mr.Nick.. This works fine for a specific entry,but mine is a more generic query..let me elaborate..

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you're looking for it's difficult to give you an answer. :)

Comment: I understand :) I've edited it to form a more specific request.

Comment: from this url "POST /processlogin.php?next=%2Fregister.php%3Ferror%3Dalreadyregistered HTTP/1.0"  you need to extract "processlogin.php?next=%2Fregister.php%3Ferror%3Dalreadyregistered HTTP"?

Comment: That was a poor example..I wouldnt need that entry at all..
Just the (let's call them ) "parent nodes"... I need to extract the content enclosed in /<content>/...in this set of entries,that would be just books n classroom..

Comment: I think that sql is not the right answer to your problem. You would have to use some regular expression with the language you're using.

Comment: I've added php tag. Wait for some regexp advice. Sorry. If you don't mind I delete my answer that it's useless. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$teststr = array(
"GET /books/fiction?id=324223",
"GET /classroom/ HTTP/1.0",
"GET /register.php HTTP/1.0",
"POST /thankyou.php HTTP/1.0",
"GET /register.php?error=alreadyregistered HTTP/1.0",
"POST /processlogin.php?next=%2Fregister.php%3Ferror%3Dalreadyregistered HTTP/1.0",
"GET /register.php?error=alreadyregistered HTTP/1.0",
"GET /books/fiction?id=324273" );

foreach( $teststr as $str )
 if( preg_match( '/\/(?P<folder>\w+)\//', $str, $match) )
   echo $match['folder']."<br />";
```

returns

```
books
classroom
books
```

Comment: This is good,Thanks :) But execution'll get time-consuming as my array size increases...

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner should do it:

```
$node = preg_replace('~^.*?/([^./]+).*$~', '$1', $string);
```

You can [see the output result at Codepad](http://codepad.org/CQZEo2YU):

```
books extracted from GET /books/fiction?id=324223
classroom extracted from GET /classroom/ HTTP/1.0
register extracted from GET /register.php HTTP/1.0
thankyou extracted from POST /thankyou.php HTTP/1.0
register extracted from GET /register.php?error=alreadyregistered HTTP/1.0
processlogin extracted from POST /processlogin.php?next=%2Fregister.php%3Ferror%3Dalreadyregistered HTTP/1.0
register extracted from GET /register.php?error=alreadyregistered HTTP/1.0
books extracted from GET /books/fiction?id=324273
```